# Is there a way to do an early exit or "return" from a view in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Does Rails offer any way to exit early or "return" from a view that is being rendered?

For example, I have a view structured as follows:

```
<h1>Your records summary</h1>

<% if @current_user.has_records? %>
  <p>You don't have any records.</p>
<% else %>
  ... long block of view emission code here ...
<% end %>
```

In non-erb code, I'd just `return` from that `if` condition, and wouldn't need to put that long block inside an `else`.  It would look like:

```
<h1>Your records summary</h1>

<% if @current_user.has_records? %>
  <p>You don't have any records.</p>
  <% return (or something) %>
<% end %>
... long block of view emission code here ...
```

Is there a way to do something like that in the erb?

**EDIT:** To be clear, **I'm not asking for alternate approaches**, such as have been suggested.  I'm not a Rails noob.  I really just want to know whether Ruby provides a mechanism for what I suggested or not.

Comment: Not really, but IMO that would probably be the wrong approach anyway. Consider instead using different templates and/or partials.

Comment: "No" is a perfectly acceptable answer.  I can't "accept" a comment, however.

Comment: Stackoverflow requires at least 15 characters for a comment/answer. So a simple "no" is not possible. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC there's no built-in mechanism for exiting a template early. This is in line with how (I think) a view layer should behave, although erb isn't quite a template engine.

The old-timey solution was to wrap your template in a `catch` and throw something from within the template, like a symbol.

You could also embed the eval inside a lambda, allowing `return` to work.

Still ew, though.

Comment: The idea of using a try/catch is somewhat hilarious.

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, but I figured I'd take the time to spare future people the hour or so of their lives trying to figure out if this is doable.

I've discovered that, as far back as Rails 3.2, this is actually possible.

It requires some knowledge of ActionView internals and I **do not** advocate anyone do this in production code.  Further, this particular implementation only works with the built-in ERB engine used by Rails which, itself, uses Erubi.

Alright, now that we're done with the warnings, on to the action!

The surprisingly simple answer is to `return @output_buffer.to_s`.

As long as you've closed all your HTML tags *before* returning, it seems to work and everything is correctly rendered.

For the curious, this output buffer is currently configured in the initializer for the [Erubi ERB handler](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.0/actionview/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb/erubi.rb).  With the rest of the work done by the underlying [Erubi::Engine implementation](https://github.com/jeremyevans/erubi/blob/1.7.1/lib/erubi.rb#L42).

I've poked around at something that provides a less brittle way to go about returning early, but I've unsuccessful so far.

Comment: this is the correct answer, we have to return something, returning `nil` causes errors if used in templates.

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 3.2.2, return inside a template works just fine for me.

```
<% return unless allowed_tags %>
```

Comment: I've used this method as well before. Can anybody give a downside to it?

Comment: @Gerry, markup before the return statement is not rendered in cases when the return is executed.

Comment: Ah, thanks @psparrow.  If I use it, I've only done it right at the top of a view before any mark up has been rendered so never noticed that.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to handle the conditional in your controller before rendering the template. There you can early `return` a different template (like the Add Record form) or the results template.

You can also offload that logic to Javascript in the view itself.

Comment: Thanks, but I know this.  I wasn't asking for an alternate approach.  Just asking if what I suggested is possible.